# Why is my flexbox layout not working properly on mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I have a simple css flexbox layout. I have written two media-queries for setting the most lower wrapper layout as column when the `min-width` is 750px. It's working perfectly on desktop browser but when I display my layout on chrome-developer-tools devices section or physical device, the most lower wrapper is not behaving as I expect.

The styling file:

Desktop:

```
@media (min-width:750px) {
html{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background-color: #E74C3C;
}

body{
    color: #ecf0f1;
    margin:0;
}
.alican_img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(../img/alican_resim.png) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.bodydiv{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.alican_img{
    align-self: center;
}

.img_alt_yazi{
    font-size: 100px;
    background-color:#b83c30 ;
    text-align: center;
}

.img_alt_banners{
    background-color: #A1362A;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 20px 50px;
}

.social{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #8a2d24;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
}


.social img{
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    padding: 15px 50px;
}
.powered    {
    display: none;
}

}
```

Mobile:

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {


html{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background-color: #E74C3C;
}

body{
    color: #ecf0f1;
    margin:0;

}
.alican_img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(../img/alican_resim.png) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.bodydiv{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.alican_img{
   align-self: center;
}

.img_alt_yazi{
    font-size: 100px;
    background-color:#b83c30 ;
    text-align: center;
}

.img_alt_banners{
    background-color: #A1362A;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 20px 50px;
}

.social{
    background-color: #8a2d24;
    display: -webkit-flex;

    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
}
.social img{
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.powered    {
    display: none;
}

}
```

This picture is what is the expected behavior. The social stuff's wrapper acts like column.

[image]

Here it acts like row as expected on wider width of 750px:

[image]

But when I open my layout in mobile browser it behaves like non-expected.

[image]

I expect that the layout of social things must be the first pic.

Thank you all

The jsfiddle but cannot set the styling: http://jsfiddle.net/8684uoko/4/

Comment: Please post the HTML. Also a live demo (e.g. jsfiddle.net) would be helpful.

Comment: the jsfiddle but cannot set the styling http://jsfiddle.net/8684uoko/4/

Comment: Using the HTML from your fiddle demo, and the CSS posted in your question, the layout seems to work as you want: http://jsfiddle.net/8684uoko/5/

Comment: No it does not,  would you see the last screenshot i've added to the question? When i open my layout on iphone 6 mobile browser, it looks like on the screenshot. The social stuffs must be layout like column not row...

Comment: Yes, I understand. When I narrow the window on the fiddle demo, the social icons are laid out in a column, just like the first image. http://jsfiddle.net/8684uoko/5/

Comment: However, for Safari browsers you may need to add vendor prefixes. Post your CSS code in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

Comment: It is laid out in a column just as the fiddle link you've sent. But must the same behavior be on a mobile browser of iphone 6 or Galaxy Nexus 4? But it is not same... They are behaving like row, unlike column.

Comment: Side note, you're using a very interesting way to organize the style, normally we do **either** mobile first **or**  desktop first, but not doing two sets all separately.

Comment: I see you got [your website](http://alicanyilmaz.net/) working now. I was posting an answer, but apparently you beat me to it. I found the solution using Chrome dev tools mobile device mode. You need to added `flex-direction: column` and `align-items: center` to the `.social` class in the mobile media query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a media query that specifically targets the iphone 6. Maybe that will make your problem go away.

```
@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 375px) // or 213.4375em or 3in or 9cm
    and (max-device-width : 667px) // or 41.6875em
    and (width : 667px) // or 41.6875em
    and (height : 375px) // or 23.4375em
    and (orientation : landscape) 
    and (color : 8)
    and (device-aspect-ratio : 375/667)
    and (aspect-ratio : 667/375)
    and (device-pixel-ratio : 2)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
{ }
```

Comment: Not helped at all :(

Comment: There could be a problem with the min and max width both being 750. I usually see like 0-399 and 400-499, etc